# Angular 2 importing custom model

Tags: angular

I'm trying to import my own module into an angular 2 project.

**Custom Model app.model.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Custom} from './custom/custom';

@NgModule({
  declarations:[ Custom],
  exports:[ Custom]
})
export class CustomModule{

}
```

**systemjs.config.js** added my custom module in folder src

```
map:{
  'custommodule':'src'
},
packages: {
      custommodule:{
        main: './app.module.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
```

**app.module.ts** trying to import custom module

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { CustomModule} from 'custommodule';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, CustomModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I get an error cann't find custommodule in the pathing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretending your `custommodule` is on the same path as `app.module.ts`, instead of:

```
import { CustomModule} from 'custommodule';
```

write:

```
import { CustomModule} from './custommodule';
```

Comment: why is pathing still required if its already defined in the systemjs.config.js  file?

Comment: you are mapping custommodule to a wrong location. try something like map:{  'custommodule':'./path/to/file' }.